# Python: Why is my async function returning None?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am running an API service with fastAPI:

main.py file, here is the problem. The data variable always returns None. This shouldn't happen:

```
@router.post('', name="invoice:create", response_model=FullInvoiceResponse, status_code=201)
async def create_invoice(request: Request, invoice: CreateInvoiceRequest):
    [etc...]
    try:
        data = await helpers.process_invoice_items(invoice.items)
    except:
    [etc...]
```

helpers.py:

```
from logging import error

async def calculate_invoicing(invoice_items: list) -> dict:
    """
    Calculate invoice totals grouping items by description and amount.
    :param invoice_items: list
    :return: dict
    """
    processed_data = {}
    for item in invoice_items:
        description, amount = itemgetter('description', 'amount')(item)
        key = f"{description}{amount}".upper().replace(' ', '')
        processed_data.setdefault(key, [item['description'], item['amount'], 0, 0])

        processed_data[key][2] += 1
        processed_data[key][3] += processed_data[key][1]
    return processed_data


async def generate_report(processed_data: dict) -> list:
    """
    Generate report from invoices.items after they being processed
    :param processed_data: dict
    :return: list
    """
    report = []
    for value in processed_data.values():
        description, amount, qtt_items, amount_accumulated = value
        report.append({
            'description': description,
            'amount': amount,
            'qtt': qtt_items,
            'total_amount': amount_accumulated,
        })
    return report

async def process_invoice_items(invoice_items: list):
    """
    Generate data about invoice.items properly grouped.
    :param invoice_items: list containing data about items in the request
    :return: list contained all items grouped by amount and description
    """
    try:
        invoice_data: dict = await calculate_invoicing(invoice_items)
        invoice_report: list = await generate_report(invoice_data)
        return invoice_report
    except TypeError:
        error("Something wrong happening while grouping invoice.items")
```

The invoice_items is something like this:

```
invoice_items = [
    {
        "chargeable": "stone.terminal.entry-fee",
        "description": "Item xya",
        "chargeable_id": "9112c",
        "amount": 59.21
    },
    {
        "chargeable": "stone.terminal.entry-fee",
        "description": "Item xyza",
        "chargeable_id": "123c",
        "amount": 31.92
    },
    {
        "chargeable": "stone.terminal.entry-fee",
        "description": "Item xyzc",
        "chargeable_id": "1234c",
        "amount": 11.03
    },
    {
        "chargeable": "stone.terminal.entry-fee",
        "description": "Item xya",
        "chargeable_id": "9112c",
        "amount": 59.21
    },
    {
        "chargeable": "stone.terminal.entry-fee",
        "description": "Item xyza",
        "chargeable_id": "123c",
        "amount": 31.92
    },

]
```

Whenever I run the code in debug mode, the data variable returns None. Is there something wrong I am not noting?

Comment: Your filename is `helpers.py` and you are calling `events.process_invoice_items`. shouldnt it be `helpers.process_invoice_items`? am i missing something here?

Comment: `except TypeError:` - you're swallowing any exceptions here and logging them - if that log output isn't included in the log you're watching, you're silently returning nothing (and thus, `None? ).

Comment: You can override the `return invoice_report` with some dummy return value and see if it's the exception that's swallowing your return value.